# Prevent Image Overlaps in Table View Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uitableview

In my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method I have the following code.

```
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Media Item", forIndexPath: indexPath) as MediaItemTableViewCell

    let mediaItem = tweet!.media[indexPath.row]

    let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: mediaItem.url)

    if imageData != nil {
        cell.mediaImage = UIImage(data: imageData!)
    } else {
        cell.mediaImage = nil
    }

    return cell
```

When I run this code my image overlaps over the `TableViewCell`.

[image]

I would love to have the image become thumbnail size and not overlap the bounds of the TableViewCell. What would be the best way to approach this? I've tried resizing the image but the image still becomes clipped. Thanks.

Comment: Have you set autolayouts for imageview and what is the height u r returning. And is that a custom cell? Please post some more information to help u

Answer (score 1):

Have you marked aspect-fit in the UIImage and clipSubviews on MediaItemTableViewCell class in interfaceBuilder? (Attached image). 
[image]

Comment: That does clip the image however now the image is only partially showing. It's as if iOS cropped a portion of the image and displayed it. I would like for the entire image to be displayed.

Comment: Correct, aspect fit does reduce the size of the image, but only shows a portion of it.

Comment: it should work with View Mode: aspect-fit or aspect-fill, but with aspect-fill you will loose the aspect ratio

Comment: are you using aspect-fit in the image or in the cell?

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion the different dynamic image sizes worked by adding `NSAutoLayoutConstraint`s to it relative to its height and width  , you might face another problem that image is not centred correctly due to its size , which could be fixed by adding a proprtional `NSAutoLayoutConstraint` programtically to it then if you ever faced.